# Can I use my mobile phone camera as a computer webcam?

Tags: webcam, phone

Is there any (free) way that I can connect a mobile phone with video camera as a web cam in the computer with Windows Operating System? For instance a traditional Nokia phone (not a very new smartphone).

Answer (score 1):

Try Mobiola's [WebCamera](http://mobiola.com/mobiola-web-camera) software.

> Turn your iPhone, BlackBerry, Windows Mobile or Symbian (Nokia only) smartphone into a high-quality wireless webcam. Connect it to a Mac (iPhone version only) or PC using a Wi-Fi connection, and share bright moments of your life that cannot be caught with a built-in webcam or USB camera!