# Treat android camera as a webcam?

Tags: android, webcam, camera

So here is the deal: I have a computer vision project on my head and I need to use external camera, because integrated one (in a laptop) is just not comfortable for testing. It would be great if I would be able to use my android smartphones camera. The problem here is that Windows HAS to recognize it as a webcam. Since I am using SimpleCV libraried, it only picks up webcam. I am able to disable the current webcam (I have a hotkey for that), so that should not be an issue. The main problem is: how to connect Android phone to windows laptop as a webcam?

Comment: You don't.  You would need to provide drivers for the camera which you cannot provide, even if the phone gave you access to the camera, while it connected to your computer.  Go out and buy a cheap USB camera.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phone as webcam](http://superuser.com/questions/296385/phone-as-webcam)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en) with SimpleCV. It's even [listed in the SimpleCV Cookbook](http://simplecv.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook.html). The code mentioned in the cookbook is:

```
jc = JpegStreamCamera("http://myname:mypasswd@ipcamera_host/stream.mjpg")
jc.getImage().save("seeyou.jpg")
```

You may need to change the stream URL if it doesn't work. `/video` or `/video?dummy=param.mjpg` seems to work for some.